# I can't find where the link code is WordPress Download Monitor - easy, but I can' remember

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, download, monitor

I have a WordPress site with a main page and a separate download page that has some text on it and 2 download links for files that the user of the site can download. I know this is dumb because I did this myself several months ago but now I can’t remember where the information that points to the 2 files is. If I go into the download page on the dashboard the text is displayed but not the links. If I go into the dashboard and click on Downloads/All Downloads (site using Download Monitor) I see a single entry (there are 2 downloads on the download page, so not sure what’s going on there) and if I then click on Edit there a screen with blanks appears. Can anyone clear this up for me? My site has Download Monitor, so is that what I’m actually using? The site works but I need to understand what’s going on.

---

[image: This is the screen on the website]

---

[image: This is the way it appears on the dashboard. Notice the 2 links at the bottom don't appear]

Comment: Maybe some screenshot(s) would be helpful...

Comment: Okay.  I can do that.  How do you upload images here?

Comment: There is a icon at the top of the editor window, which let's you do that

Comment: I do not see any icons on this window, the "Add Comment" window.  Please direct me to the correct window.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Two screenshots should now be visible.  The links that I am refering to are in red type.  Where would I find this code in the dashboard if I wanted to modify it?